# Which email address was this email sent to?

Tags: email, outlook, ms-office

I get a lot of emails in my inbox via various distributions lists / aliases, and I want to know exactly which address was used for a particular email.

The "To" shows the sender's name, there are no addresses in the CC field, so I imagine I received this as a BCC.

This is Outlook 2010 on Windows 7, at work.

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: No. Is there a better place to ask? I saw the tags so assumed the subject was allowed.

Comment: Open the message, click the small "+" button in the lower right corner of the Tag group on the ribbon. You will see the original message headers.

Comment: Thanks. Do you want to post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the message, click the small "+" button in the lower right corner of the Tag group on the ribbon. You will see the original message headers.